Can CoUninitialize throw "80070006 The handle is invalid" exception
From the documentation provided by Microsoft, I could not find any note on whether CoUninitialize could raise an exception. This has occurred in random.
Code context: In every thread my exe branches out, the function CoInitialize() is called and at the end of the function CoUninitialize() is also called.
ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80070006 - The handle is invalid.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80070006

STACK_TEXT:  
05eefa3c 778ae813     80070006 00000001 00000000 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x62
05eefa50 778fcd18     0172b4e8 77895e7a 016d0b20 combase!Microsoft::WRL::Details::RaiseException+0xd
05eefa64 77895e0d     0172b4e8 05a84370 016d0b20 combase!Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleT<Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleTraits::EventTraits>::Close+0xa9333
05eefa74 777ff0c1     05a8438c 05a84370 00000101 combase!CComApartment::~CComApartment+0x74
05eefa8c 77803627     05eefafc 016d0b20 00000000 combase!CObjectContext::~CObjectContext+0xaa
05eefab0 77852b89     779aeb68 05a844e0 05eefae0 combase!CObjectContext::InternalRelease+0xc9
05eefac0 77852a43     01708378 01708378 00000000 combase!DecrementProcessInitializeCount+0x44
05eefae0 77847259     05eefb58 00796af8 00000000 combase!wCoUninitialize+0xa5
05eefb58 003b3ee3     0038ead0 0038ead0 00000000 combase!CoUninitialize+0xf9


From the stack trace, you can see that the exception is being thrown from a Close of a HandleT. Probably the handle is invalid, either because (1) somebody corrupted the memory that holds the handle, or (2) somebody called CloseHandle() and closed that handle accidentally (say due to an uninitialized variable or a double-close). Check your program to make sure it doesn't close handles it shouldn't. You can turn on Application Verifier's Handle verification to help identify who closed the handle.

@RaymondChen and it doesn't bother you : +0xa9333 offset ? definitelly this is not from Close of a HandleT . something related to ApartmentShutdownNode::Release() is called on _spFirstShutdownCallback or _spSentinelForNotify but without look under debugger hard say what is going

@RbMm The fact that we're seeing non-exported functions gives me more confidence in the a9333. The failure case was probably moved by PGO to a rarely-used page. I looked on my machine, and tracing through HandleT::Close takes me to a RaiseException at combase!Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleT<Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleTraits::EventTraits>::Close+0x1115ae.

@RaymondChen of course this is moved case ("unlikely") out of function body. but probably here IApartmentShutdown::Release called on _spFirstShutdownCallback member of CComApartment. somebody register this callback. and need loook under debugger

i be even guess that somebody can call CoRegisterForApartmentShutdown ( #120 ordinal in combase) despite it very rarelly call. in any case interesting look this under debugger

@RaymondChen based on you comment CloseHandle() being called on an invalid handle but, the stack starts from the CoUninitialize being called. I wonder does this have to do with the handle being closed.

CoUninitialize is cleaning up stuff, and one of the things it's cleaning up is a handle, but the handle has gone invalid.
